# Save linked list to use later

Tags: c, linked-list

So I wrote this code: 
code: https://repl.it/JA1s/4

```
int list_Size(link_t *anchor);
void menu(link_t *list);
void freeMemory(link_t *list);
void freeLink(link_t *list);

void writeListToFile();

#include "view.h"
#include "linkedList.h"

int main(void) {
    link_t *anchor = NULL;
    system("COLOR 81");
    int choise = 0;
    printf("Welcome!\nPress 0 to make a new list\npress any other key to load an existing listing");
    scanf("%d", &choise);
    if (choise == 0) {
        menu(anchor);
        return 0;
    }
    if (choise != 0) {
        anchor=readList(anchor);
    }
}

void menu(link_t* anchor) {
    unsigned int number = 0, choice = 0, num = 0, ans = 0;
    char* name = (char*)malloc(MAX_NAME_SIZE);
    if (name) {
        if (anchor) {
            freeMemory(anchor);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    while (number == 0) {
        do {
            printf("Welcome to Magshimim Movie Maker! what would you like to do? \n");
            printf("[0] exit\n");
            printf("[1] Add new Frame\n");
            printf("[2] Remove a Frame\n");
            printf("[3] change frame index\n");
            printf("[4] Change frame duration\n");
            printf("[5] Change duration of all frames\n");
            printf("[6] List frames\n");
            printf("[7] Play movie!\n");
            printf("[8] Save List to file");
            scanf("%d", &choice);
            getchar();
            switch (choice) {
            case 0:
                freeMemory(anchor);
                number = 1;
                break;
            case 1:
                addNewPic(&anchor);
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("Enter the frame's name:   ");
                fgetsMe(name, MAX_NAME_SIZE);
                removePic(&anchor, name);
                break;
            case 3:
                changePosition(&anchor);
                break;
            case 4:
                printf("Enter the frame's name:   ");
                fgetsMe(name, MAX_NAME_SIZE);
                durationSong(anchor, name);
                break;
            case 5:
                printf("enter a num \n");
                scanf("%d", &num);
                getchar();
                durationOfAll(anchor, num);
                break;
            case 6:
                display(anchor);
                system("pause");
                break;
            case 7:
                playMenu(anchor);
                break;
            case 8:
                writeListToFile(anchor);
                break;
            default:
                printf("you write a not currect number\n");
            }
            system("CLS");
        } while (choice < 0 || choice > 7);
    }
}

void freeMemory(link_t* list) {
    link_t* temp = NULL;
    while (list) {
        temp = list;
        list = list->next;
        freeLink(temp);
    }
}

link_t *readNextFromFile(link_t *anchor, FILE *pfile) {
    size_t returnValue;
    if (anchor == NULL) {
        anchor = malloc(sizeof(link_t));
        returnValue = fread(anchor, sizeof(link_t), 1, pfile);
        anchor->next = NULL;
        anchor->prevoius = NULL;
    } else {
        link_t *index = anchor;
        link_t *neww = malloc(sizeof(link_t));
        while (index->next != NULL) {
            index = index->next;
        }
        returnValue = fread(neww, sizeof(link_t), 1, pfile);
        index->next = neww;
        neww->next = NULL;
        neww->prevoius = index;
    }
}

link_t *readList(link_t *anchor) {
    int loop = 0;
    FILE *pfile;
    pfile = fopen("s.bin", "rb");
    if (pfile != NULL) {
        anchor = NULL;

        fseek(pfile, 0, SEEK_END);
        long filesize = ftell(pfile);//tell what is the size
        rewind(pfile);  //get back to the start before we start reading it 
        int numEntries = (int)(filesize / (sizeof(link_t)));

        for (loop = 0; loop < numEntries; loop++) {
            //looping through the struct
            fseek(pfile, (sizeof(link_t)*loop), SEEK_SET);
            anchor = readNextFromFile(anchor, pfile);
        }
        menu(anchor);
    } else {
        printf("File open error\n");
    }
    return anchor;
}

void writeListToFile(link_t **anchor) {
    FILE *pfile;
    pfile = fopen("s.bin", "wb");
    if (pfile != NULL) {
        link_t *current = anchor;
        link_t *prev = NULL;
        link_t *next = NULL;
        while (current != NULL) {
            next = current->next;
            prev = current->prevoius;

            current->next = NULL;
            current->prevoius = NULL;

            fseek(pfile, 0, SEEK_END);
            fwrite(current, sizeof(link_t), 1, pfile);

            current->next = next;
            current->prevoius = prev;

            next = NULL;
            prev = NULL;

            current = current->next;
        }
        fclose(pfile);
    } else {
        printf("File Open Error!");
        pfile = NULL;
    }
}
```

linkedList.h: https://repl.it/JA1s/2

```
#ifndef LINKEDLISTH
#define LINKEDLISTH

#include "Frame.h"

struct Link {
    frame_t *frame;
    struct Link *next;
    struct Link *prevoius;
};

typedef struct Link link_t;
#endif
```

view.h: https://repl.it/JA1s/3

```
#include <opencv2\core\core_c.h>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui_c.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "linkedList.h"

void play(link_t *list);
```

frame.h

```
#ifndef FRAME_H
#define FRAME_H

#include <stdio.h>

struct Frame
{
    char            *name;
    unsigned int    duration;
    char            *path;  // may change to FILE*
};

typedef struct Frame frame_t;


#define MAX_PATH_SIZE (256)
#define MAX_NAME_SIZE (50)

#endif //FRAME_H
```

My problem comes when I press anything other then 0 at the start to load an existing bin file with a linked list that i've created. I get the error: 
`Unhandled exception at 0x003C1043` at `while (index->next != NULL){`. What is the reason?

Comment: The code goes *verbatim* into the question please. If it's too much code for this, you're supposed to create an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (which may also help you to discover the problem yourself) -- thanks.

Comment: done. Minimalized the code

Comment: @Yoni G -- almost ;) Paste it in your question please, questions here should be *self-contained* and not depend on external sites. To format it as code, indent it by 4 spaces (easiest way is select all the code and hit `Ctrl+K`).

Comment: Please do not edit the question to correct bugs from the comments and answers: it makes the discussion inconsistent.

Comment: if you've been exposed to JAVA: please forget it.

Answer (score 0):

You must open the file in binary mode for `fread` and `fwrite` to handle binary data properly.  This is probably not the only problem, but definitely a major one for a Windows host.  Use this:

```
pfile = fopen("s.bin", "rb");
```

Furthermore, you cannot save this list to disk this way:

- You effectively save NULL pointers for the `next` and `previous` links, but the list payload is also a pointer `frame_t *frame;` which will be irrelevant when you reload its value from a previous run.
- Saving the current state of your program is called *serialization*.  You must use a file format that is independent of the memory layout.  Using a text based format such as JSON is highly advisable to easy debugging and portability.

Here is a function to save the list in JSON format:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int writeListToFile(const link_t *list) {
    FILE *pfile = fopen("s.json", "w");
    if (pfile != NULL) {
        fprintf(pfile, "[\n");
        for (; list != NULL; list = list->next) {
            fprintf("  { "\"name\": \"%s\", \"duration\": %u, \"path\": \"%s\" },\n",
                    list->frame->name, list->frame->duration, list->frame->path);
        }
        fprintf(pfile, "]\n");
        fclose(pfile);
        return 1;
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open s.json: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Notes:

- This function assumes the frame members are properly allocated and the strings do not contain any special characters such as `"`, `\` and newline.
- The function to read this back into memory is a bit more difficult to write, but a simple approach is to assume the format is fixed.

Comment: seems like if I change the format to JSON the problem is in the free functuion

Comment: How do you change the format to JSON?  just changing the file extension does not do it;-)  You must write code to produce JSON data and parse it upon load, this is non trivial.

Comment: Well, it creates a JSON file if I change it from bin. And the error changes (see the edit)

Comment: No, it does not create a JSON file just by changing the extension.  I meant writing data as JSON contents, which looks like this: `{ "name": "value", ... }`. JSON might not be appropriate for your problem, we have no idea what a `frame_t` contains, but storing the pointer into a file is bogus.

Comment: updated the frame content. So the problem is in the while loop. It only checks if the next is not NULL

Comment: Thank you, but seems I get Unhandled exception at 0x7715FF33 at list->frame->name, list->frame->duration, list->frame->path

Comment: if `list->frame` is null, you have undefined behavior.  It is time to start using a debugger.